# How to access array element correctly from JSON in Angular 5 app?

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have the following JSON definition:

```
export class Company {
  name: string;
  trips : Trip[] = [];
}
```

I am able to see the trips in the console using:

```
console.log(this.company);
```

But I am not able to access the array elements (trip), I've tried
the following:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.company.trips.length; i++){
        console.log(this.company.trips[i]);      
  }
```

When I display the company to the log I'm getting the trip as you can 
see below:

```
{id: 1}
name: "Sample"
trips: {id: 1, r: "ABC"}
id: 1
```

Any idea how to access array elements in Angular thanks?

Comment: the variable is called trip ... not trips.  change the name in the class. trips: Trip[].  Also when console. logging like this it will just show "Object" if you dont specify a property of trips

Comment: it was a typo, I update the question to "trips" as it should be.

Comment: I am curious, how he wrote that code. It will throw error right.

Comment: yes. it would.  but i guess he typed it instead of copying.

Comment: in .ts the array index begings by 0, so for (let i=0;i<this.company.trips.length;i++) -use "let, not var", and begind by 0-. By the way you must sure this.company.trips are not null. You can use trips : Trip[]=[]

Comment: I've update the question with the fix propose but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2304483 `trips` in your log is an object, not an array. Maybe you set it to object instead of adding object to array at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `Object.keys()` and `forEach()` will let you iterate through the the object in a similar fashion to an array.

**explination**

```js
const x = {hello: "hi"};  
console.log(Object.keys(x)); // will return array looking like 

// [hello] which you can run a for each on.

Object.keys(x).forEach(data => {
    console.log(x[data]); // will return `hi`
});
```

**Solution**

```js
const trips = {id: 1, r: "ABC"}; // const trips = this.company.trips

if (trips) // check the value exists here 
  {
    Object.keys(trips).forEach((data) => {
    console.log(trips[data]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your solution work, I am able to see in the log now: 1 ABC but from some reason it show multiple times, something like 30 times.

Comment: Be sure that you only call this function once i would imagine that would be where you are getting an issue.

Comment: Your solution works so I'm going to solve this question and open a new one for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.company)
     this.Company.trips.forEach(x => {
            console.log(x);
        });
```

Comment: I ma getting: ERROR TypeError: this.company.trips.forEach is not a function

Comment: Yes it is as you can see in my question.

Comment: if it is array, you might not get forEach is not an function error. better show your sample response.